# Soql queries limit

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am trying to store the soql queries in a transaction for a particular object

via record triggered after save flow order of execution for that flow is last it is considering everything for limit.getqueries() except for other record triggered flow which is creating child records based on our object while debug log is considering that soql queries part of that same transaction what might be the cause and anyother way we can store this soql queries count

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.